# Subtract 2 text dimensions in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I wanted to know if it is possible to subtract 2 dimensions which are text fields. For eg.

```
Kpi Name                 Jun     May    Apr
$Deposits                234     567    321
```

Here I have Kpi name in rows and date in columns. Kpi_value is text.Is it possible to take difference between Jun value and May Value? If this difference is positive I want to put a colored shape next to it.

Thanks!

Comment: You have three months in column (and I assume there would be many more going forward!) so how do you decide which months subtraction you require to calculate? Is it just `max(month) - (max(month) - 1month)` or something more than this? I would recommend you to please update your question with as much more information you can so that we can guide you in right direction. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct..subtract the values of latest month from previous month but please note the values are text not a measure. Hope this helps.

Comment: First thing: if this is how you are going to organise the data, it is far from ideal if you have multiple dates. You should store the data as *three* columns: KPI name; Date; value. Then the addition of new dates won't require you to alter the data structure. This ill make future analysis much easier.

Comment: @peppy can't dimension be converted into measure by right clicking the field name (as values are numeric!)? And as highlighted by matt_black I believe you should pay attention to his advise as it'll make your calculation and other approach much easier. Thanks!